# Where can I check the list of all sponsored stories I "liked"

Tags: facebook, privacy

Sometimes I see my friends associated to Facebook ads:

```
Sponsored Stories
John Doe likes SomeProduct.
```

I might have clicked "Like" on some things without being aware this would end up being used like this.

To avoid this, is there a place where I can see the list of all sponsored stories I "liked"?

I have looked here:

> Profile > Info > Activities and Interests: Edit > Show Other Pages

But I am not sure if this the correct place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this info using the Graph API. One way to do this is to go to the Graph API info page - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Here you will see links to get information about yourself (Profile details, Likes, Photo Albums...). These links contain an access token which is only valid for a short time so you cannot bookmark these links.

Comment: Indeed. So, what I described is the "Likes: https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=..." link?

Comment: Yes that should give you all your Likes info

Answer (score 0):

You could view https://www.facebook.com/ads/adboard/
, which shows you the different links which are ads-related.

Some of the ads would have likes on the bottom.

Comment: It shows me 26 ads. A few of them are liked by friends, but none by me it seems. Does that mean I like zero ads, or is the Adboard just a selection of a few ads?